# Ubuntu 12.04 ltib package issue

Tags: 12.04, package-management

I tried to install the `ltib` package and the following errors were displayed :

```
Package                Minimum ver   Installed info
-------                -----------   ---------------
glibc-devel            0             not installed
zlib                   0             not installed

Died at ./ltib line 1397.
traceback:
 main::host_checks:1397
  main:542
```

What should i do to resolve such errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try again after installing :

```
sudo apt-get install zlib nsis-common fossology-agents zlib1g eglibc glibc-doc
```